# XMPP SASL Authentication

Tags: xmpp, sasl

I am trying to create an XMPP server library for an XMPP-based application I will be developing.
I am stuck on trying to authenticate the client with plain SASL. I have already read the RFC at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-6.4.6

My problem is that after sending a <success />, receiving and sending a new  open tag and an empty features list, the client (Pidgin) proceeds to authenticate using non-SASL authentication. This is a log of the communication (<< means incoming, >> outgoing):

```
<<  <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream to='127.0.0.1' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>

>>  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>>  <stream:stream version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:server" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="kanapka" from="127.0.0.1">
>>  <stream:features>
>>  <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
>>  <mechanism>
>>  PLAIN
>>  </mechanism>
>>  </mechanisms>
>>  </stream:features>

<<  <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN' xmlns:ga='http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth' ga:client-uses-full-bind-result='true'>AHRlc3R1c2VyAHRlc3RwYXNz</auth>

>>  <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" />

<<  <stream:stream to='127.0.0.1' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>

>>  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>>  <stream:stream version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:server" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="hotdog" from="127.0.0.1">
>>  <stream:features />

<<  <iq type='get' id='purple46cbc043'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:auth'><username>testuser</username></query></iq>
```

I am not yet using TLS, nor have I tried any other SASL mechanism. This is all plain text.

This is the same TCP connection, the IDs of streams are different. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not advertising support for resource binding, so the client can't complete the session setup. It seems Pidgin decides then to fall back on jabber:iq:auth (pre-XMPP style) if the server doesn't support XMPP-style stream setups.

You'll want to take a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-7 as "Support for resource binding is REQUIRED in XMPP client and server implementations." and "The parties to a stream MUST consider resource binding as mandatory-to-negotiate."

While implementing XMPP by looking at what other implementations do, rather than following the specs, is not a good idea, sometimes taking a glance at another implementation's stream can give a clue when you get stuck like this.